# JBoss gettingstarted.zip

Tags: jboss, jakarta-ee

I am looking for the gettingstarted.zip or the examples in the jboss tutorial, but could not find them, especially the sources for the jsfejb3 example. Are these examples removed from the distribution or am I to stupid to find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the example shown in http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.3/html-single/Getting_Started_Guide/index.html#About_the_Example_Applications ?

If so it's available in the "Application Platform 4.3.0.GA_CP09 documentation" available from https://access.redhat.com/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

this might be what you are looking for [JBOSS Start Guide.zip](https://web.archive.org/web/20110116173131/http://www.iomule.com:80/JBoss/), also maybe try JBoss Sourceforge page

edit: try this maybe [JSF-EJB3 Example](https://web.archive.org/web/20120109074820/http://community.jboss.org:80/wiki/SampleJSF-EJB3Application)

and these guys [LINK](https://developer.jboss.org/message/251569) seem to have got working what you are having trouble with maybe something in thier posts can help

Comment: Not exactly. I also browsed the sourceforge pages but could not find them the sources of the tutorial. It seems they vanished into thin air.

Comment: @headmyshoulder I have added a couple other links to some pages that might help

Comment: Thank you, nevertheless I can not find them. I looks like they have been completely removed. I browser nearly all distributions of jboss on sf and searched on the redhat page without success. (Edit: some typos)